# On my Magento store I cannot login on the frontend and cannot add items to my shopping cart after upgrading to 1.4.2. Any ideas what's wrong

Tags: magento, session, magento-1.4

I have just upgraded my Magento shopping cart to 1.4.2. Since the upgrade when I try to login on the frontend the page refreshes, but there's no evidence of being logged in. If I try to login with the wrong credentials I get an error message. I figured that it might be a session problem so I tried adding an item to my cart. When I do that I get an error message that says, "Cannot add the item to shopping cart." This might be an unrelated problem. Was wondering if anyone has any ideas where to look. Adding an item to the shopping cart adds the following line to the log:

```
DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'additional_table.is_visible_on_front' in 'field list'
```

Trace: #0 /var/www/magentobase/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Logging in produces no errors.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its been fixed. The problem was that I wasn't thorough enough in re-indexing and flushing the cache. To get it working I:

1. Flushed Magento Cache and Cache
   storage by pushing the buttons in
   System -> Cache Management
2. Refreshed the cache by checking all
   the items under System -> Cache and
   selecting "Refresh"
3. Reindexed everything by going to
   System -> Index Management and
   selecting all times and then
   selecting "Reindex Data".

I hope this helps!